# Perfect forwarding and copy elision of local variable

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, copy-elision

I'd like to create a function that should return an rvalue reference when called with an rvalue reference as an argument. Otherwise, it should return a copy of its argument.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr inline auto is_const_reference_v = is_const_v<remove_reference_t<T>>;

template <typename T>
constexpr inline auto is_mutable_rvalue_reference_v =
    is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&> && !is_const_reference_v<T>;

// Forward mutable rvalue refs
template <typename T, class =
    enable_if_t<is_mutable_rvalue_reference_v<T>>
>
T&& copy_if_lvalue_or_const_ref (T&& t)
{
    return move(t);
}

// Copy anything else
template <typename T>
decay_t<T> copy_if_lvalue_or_const_ref (T& t)
{
    return t;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/G6zcabbTY)

Next, I'd like to create a function that should save the result of copy_if_lvalue_or_const_ref in a temporary variable, call `do_smth` method on it and return this variable.

Possible solution:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) do_smth_and_pass(T&& t)
{
    decltype(auto) tmp = copy_if_lvalue_or_const_ref(std::forward<T>(t));
    tmp.do_smth();
    if constexpr (is_mutable_rvalue_reference_v<T>)
    {
        return static_cast<T&&>(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        return tmp; // copy elision does not work.
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/PGT8x9o9b)

Unfortunately, copy elision does not work for lvalues, `return tmp;` calls move constructor.

I found the solution using two functions:

```
template <typename T, enable_if_t<is_mutable_rvalue_reference_v<T>>* = nullptr>
decltype(auto) do_smth_and_pass(T&& t)
{
    decltype(auto) tmp = copy_if_lvalue_or_const_ref(std::forward<T>(t));
    tmp.do_smth();
    return static_cast<T&&>(tmp);
}

template <typename T, enable_if_t<!is_mutable_rvalue_reference_v<T>>* = nullptr>
decay_t<T> do_smth_and_pass(T&& t)
{
    decltype(auto) tmp = copy_if_lvalue_or_const_ref(std::forward<T>(t));
    tmp.do_smth();
    return tmp;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Kbb16nv9f)

I do not like it, though. It is not generic enough. Is it possible to make the same with a single function?

Comment: `if constexpr` perhaps on return?

Comment: Do note that if you declare a variable inside a function, that variable doesn't qualify for guaranteed RVO.  You might get NRVO as a compiler optimization, but otherwise the object will be treated as an rvalue in the return statement and moved out of the function if it is moveable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a member function on the object before returning it, then there is no way to guarantee copy elision.

Both of your attempts are equivalent: Both allow for, but do not guarantee, named return value optimization (NVRO) to be applied so that the result object of the function call is the same object as `tmp`. It is up to the compiler under which circumstances it applies this optimization.